# how to determine whether the issue is hard drive or hard drive controller?

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery, diagnostic

I have an HP Compaq 620 laptop that suddenly stopped working
The BIOS doesn't detect the hard disk at all, but there are no other signs of failure (weird hdd noises etc)
The bios system diagnostics tests (start-up test, run-in test) show

Failed
Disk not installed

It's as if there is no hdd at all in the computer

I've tried removing the hdd and plugging back in, and there is no difference

I can still boot up through puppy slacko (ver 5 I think) installed on the sd card using the laptop's built in sdcard reader, but there is no sign of hdd, either in Puppy Linux itself or gparted

I'm pretty sure the hdd is dead at this point, but is there anything else I can do to recover it?

Is it at least possible to rule out the possibility of the motherboard's hdd controller failure,  before I buy a new hard drive? **I only have the portable install of Puppy Slacko to work with(no extra hdd's or laptops)**

Edit 1:
An option called boot order shows "Notebook hard drive" as one of the boot options. In the past I have seen some bioses only show bootable hardware that are actually physically present in this list. Is this bios dependent, or is it an indication the hdd is still detected by the bios at some level?

I've also noticed that SATA device mode is set to AHCI and only other option is IDE. Changing it to IDE gives a warning that I might have to reinstall my OS. I don't know what this option does. Is it worth giving it a shot or will this not affect anything?

There is another option called UEFI boot mode which is set to disabled. Enabling it gives a warning that UEFI boot mode is only for development purposes and recommends to keep it disabled, and some other BIOS settings should be disabled first if I want to enable UEFI boot mode anyway ( I don't know what or where these other settings are in the bios).What is this setting and should I try enabling it?

Comment: you could try a different HDD in the laptop, or try using the suspect HDD in another PC as a storage drive.

Comment: @drudge I don't have extra hdd's or laptops thats tje whole point

Comment: @user13267 - If you have no other HDDs or you don't have another device you can connect the HDD to, then you don't have the tools to determine if the problem is caused by the SATA controller or the HDD.  So you will have to go out and purchase an external SATA controller (i.e. a USB enclosure) or another HDD.

Comment: Changing your SATA mode won't affect anything.  But, if that's the issue you'd still see the hard drive and get a boot failure related to that versus a missing hard drive

Comment: @ramhound I was afraid of that being the case. Thanks everyone. I noticed later that the hdd does make clicking sounds when trying to boot ( a fan running nearby was blocking out the sound previously). I guess I don't have a choice but to get a new hdd at this point.

Comment: In 20 years of IT work I had 1 bad hard drive controller and countless hard drives. A bad hard drive is the most likely case.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm pretty sure the hdd is dead at this point, but is there anything
>   else I can do to recover it?

Dozens of data recovery services exist.  Drivesavers is only one among dozens, and you should check the reviews and get estimates.

You could try spinrite by steve gibson @ grc.com

However, if that doesn't work, its $70 you'll wish you had when you get the bill from the experts.